# Nginx redirect only specific paths of a server from http to https

Tags: windows, nginx, http-redirect

I want to redirect the paths from http to https like the following:

- http://localhost:80/ to same Http url
- http://localhost:80/api/ to https://localhost:80/api/ which in turn redirects to https://localhost:55555/api/

I have a configuration file:

```
worker_processes  1;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name localhost;

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS server
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;     

        ssl_certificate certs/myservice.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key certs/myservice.key;

        server_name myservice.com localhost;

        location /api/ {

                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_pass https://localhost:55555/api/;

                client_max_body_size 500G;

                proxy_connect_timeout       300;
                proxy_send_timeout          300;
                proxy_read_timeout         3600;
                send_timeout                300;

        }

        location / {

                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

                proxy_pass http://localhost:80/;

                client_max_body_size 500G;

                proxy_connect_timeout       300;
                proxy_send_timeout          300;
                proxy_read_timeout         3600;
                send_timeout                300;

        }
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
}
```

When i tried with this, the second requirement was fulfilled. But the first one of keeping http://localhost:80/  the same fails. It is unnecessarily redirected as https://localhost .

In short, nginx redirects all the HTTP requests coming to port 80 on the localhost server to HTTPS.

I also tried removing the location / { } section from second server block.

Then tried specifying in fist server block as:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:80/
        }

        location /api/ {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}
```

Both of them didn't worked.

What is the correct way of redirecting only specific paths of a server from http to https in Nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This section in the second server block won't work. Because it again redirects to https.

```
location / {

                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

                proxy_pass http://localhost:80/;

                client_max_body_size 500G;

                proxy_connect_timeout       300;
                proxy_send_timeout          300;
                proxy_read_timeout         3600;
                send_timeout                300;

        }
```

So exposed that application to a different host port other than 80, say 88. Then changed this proxypass URL to:

```
 proxy_pass http://localhost:88/;
```

Now it works fine.